# Forge Model Derivatives: GET metadata always returns 202 when using SVF2 format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

My Postman REST {urn}/metadata/{guid} requests are always responing with status code 202 since a few days when using SVF2 format. When using SVF 1 format with the same requests I get a valid JSON response. The result is working in the Viewer and I also can use other formats like IFC.

My request URL is `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/regions/eu/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}`

Before that my SVF2 request have worked.

Comment: Are you passing the header `x-ads-force: true` when calling this API? If not, could you share the URN and GUID you passed to this call? We can help consult our engineering team for insights. If you don't want to share URN and GUID publicly, please consider contacting `forge (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`.

Comment: I have send an URN and GUID to the email address. The header `x-ads-force: true`  is set.